# Namenode Recovery

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, recovery

We know that Namenode will maintain metadata in memory and periodically(1hr by default) Secondary Namenode will collect that data and persist for backup.
If the Namenode gone down after 55 mins of secondary namenode periodic collected data, how the hdfs system will manage lost data of Namenode at the time of  Namenode recovery?

Answer (score 0):

Good point, that's the one reason we say NameNode is single point of failure [(SPOF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure).

Check out the [HDFS HA](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2_1.html) as a solution

Comment: Thansk zhutoulala for your reply and helpful link given by you

Answer (score 0):

As per Hadoop gen 1 there is no way to cover data for those 55 mins.
But I think this can be managed in Hadoop gen 2 where we have active and passive namenode